# Creating a 'bot' to essentially login to a website and click a few buttons (approx. 3 buttons if it matters)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

[image]Okay before you continue reading please note that I am not proficient in programming and am just getting by using what I find on the internet that's applicable.
I'm trying to get code a bot to login to the website of my gym everyday at the same time and book me a spot on the hour when they open (because the spots for working out get taken very fast).

I'm stuck trying to get my computer to recognize that I have the chromedriver.exe and I thought I put the path location in correctly but maybe not.
I'm not sure if I'm even onto something or not but this is what I've got so far:
it looks like I can't upload more images for some reason but I'm getting errors like
"'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH."

Before this I directly extracted the path location from my file chromedriver.exe (which I followed the install for for Mac) and put it in the paths section of terminal and saved.

I'm not sure this is even the problem but if anyone has a solution or even advice I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have an example of this part of code? Would be easier to assist.

Comment: @Sai I've added the code I've got so far. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I re-reviewed your error. The error of importance is the one that says `No such file or directory /path/to/chromedriver.exe`. I'm guessing in your code you have a reference to `chromedriver.exe` at that path that doesn't exist. Replace that with the real path to your chromedriver.

**Leaving this for historical record:**

The error is indicating that the `chromdriver.exe` is not in your path

if you run `echo $PATH` in your terminal, you will see list of directories that your machine will search for binary/executables in. You need to add `chromedriver.exe` into one of those directories.

Edit:
If moving `chromedriver.exe` into one of those already existing directories is not an option, you can also add the directory it is in to your PATH. [This](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/appleosx-bash-unix-change-set-path-environment-variable/) details several options for mac on how do to so. The simplest way is to add

`export PATH=$PATH:/new/dir/location1` to your ~/.bash_profile

Comment: I'm fairly sure I did this though and that's why I was confused. I right clicked on chromediver.exe and got its path location directly from there, then put it in the part of the terminal you mentioned. Is there something I'm missing or not doing correctly?

Comment: @Prez7112 for the full path you need a drive letter. I assume you're on Windows as you have a .exe, so it'd probably be `C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe`.

Comment: Looking at the screencap of your code you have `browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/path/to/chromedriver.exe)`. looks like you should replace that with `browser_path`